# i am building zoom clone(flutter) using jitsi meet ,while runing the app on android emulator i am getting these error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test

1:19 Error:
android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : android:exported needs to be explicitly specified for element <service#org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService>. Apps targeting Android 12 and higher are required to specify an explicit value for `android:exported` when the corresponding component has an intent filter defined. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#exported for details.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             11.3s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
➜  untitled1

Comment: Which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

have you resolved this yet? if not, paste the below code inside the '<application></application>' of your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application>
...
        <service
       android:name="org.jitsi.meet.sdk.ConnectionService"
       android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TELECOM_CONNECTION_SERVICE"
       android:exported="true">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.telecom.ConnectionService" />
       </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: this is not working in android 12